# Implementing Barcode Scanning Without installing barcode application

Tags: android, barcode, zxing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Integration ZXing library directly into my Android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782543/integration-zxing-library-directly-into-my-android-application)

I want scan the barcode from my Android App without installing a 3rd party barcoder scanner application. I downloaded the source code of ZXing. When I click a button in my App, the barcode scanning window should launch. What are the methods that I need to call from my application  for successful scanning of barcodes.

Can anyone please help me in sorting out this issue?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: is there anyone who can help me in sorting out this issue?

Comment: I don't understand why you would want to do this? Why can't you just call the ZXing 2D barcode intent. Saves code duplication and complexity?

Comment: I know but there may be situations where the user who installs my app donot have ZXing application to be pre installed on his device.My application is mainly dependent on Barcode scanning.So,can any one help me in sorting out this issue?

Comment: Hello I think this might help you..

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4854442/embed-zxing-library-without-using-barcode-scanner-app

Comment: Answered it on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782543/integration-zxing-library-directly-into-my-android-application/34941618#34941618