# ZXingScannerView scan area full screen

Tags: android, android-layout, zxing

I am scanning QR codes in my app, using ZXingScannerView. By default, the scan area is small, with a border. I want it fullscreen. Is there any way to do it?

This is my code:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_top">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/backbutton"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
        android:text="@string/back"
        android:textColor="@color/white"/>

    <me.dm7.barcodescanner.zxing.ZXingScannerView
        android:id="@+id/scanview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/backbutton"
        barcodescanner:shouldScaleToFill="true"/>



</RelativeLayout>

protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.scan_layout);
    scannerView=findViewById(R.id.scanview);
    //scannerView.setLaserColor(getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
    scannerView.setLaserEnabled(false);
    scannerView.setShouldScaleToFill(true);
    (...)
}
```

As you can see, I tried setShoulScaleToFill(true); but it does not work.

Is there any way to do it?

Thank you.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41392426/how-to-zxing-barcode-scanner-not-full-screen-only-half-screen

Comment: I have checked it but it is not using ZXingScannerView...

Comment: check this issue https://github.com/dm77/barcodescanner/issues/67

Comment: You pointed me in the right direction, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You should try using [CameraX](https://medium.com/@natiginfo/building-qr-code-scanner-for-android-using-firebase-ml-kit-and-camerax-1481f6f8bf9a), it's easy and the camera is the size you define it

Comment: I have the Camera in full screen. It shows a preview area where the QR code is scanned, with a border, in the center of the screen. I want the scan area to be full screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Width/HeightRequest