# Creating a stanadlone QR Code scanner

Tags: android, qr-code

I want to know how to begin with creating a basic QR Code scanner. I dont want any application Intent to be called. I want to know how my Camera intent can be started in QRCode scan mode, and how the result can be used. My application is only for String. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you referring to android?

Comment: the question is tagged **android**...

Comment: @binnyb: I did that after Daniel asked the question. It involves intents, so I figure it must be Android.

Comment: Yes guys.. Its for android. Any help? :)

Comment: This is what you are searching for : 
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782543/integration-zxing-library-directly-into-my-android-application

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at googles zxing [here](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/), its open source so you can have a look at how they achieve it. Hope this helps.