# Integration ZXing library into my Android application

Tags: android, import, zxing

[image]

I just updated to the question below... I alr sorted the build thing out since I did it in the wrong path...but I still got the follow error ! 
Need helps since I don't understand what it is ! :)  Thank you !

=================================

I need some helps ! I got the error message while I am doing ”ant -f core/build.xml" I got the

Buildfile:core.build.xml doesn't exist ! Buildfail !

I followed the steps from this :[Integrating the ZXing library directly into my Android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782543/integration-zxing-library-directly-into-my-android-application)

How do we sort it out? :)

Thank you ! I am trying to use Scanner in my app

Comment: Why don't you just use the IntentIntegrator of zxing. That way you don't have to integrate the code into your app and you don't have to update the zxing code, if they have a new version. The IntentIntegrator makes sure that "Barcode Scanner" is installed and the Market keeps it updated. In my opinion that's a very elegant solution.

Comment: hey Henrik, true but I am running it in Android  Dummy device for Eclipse right now. But I think I will just use my Android phone to run the files.. it must be much easier !

Comment: I think I will just try to run it on my actual Android ! as you said, it might be much easier ! =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to folder which is root folder for zxing project ( may be "zxing" is the name of root folder) from cmd prompt.

Make sure you have ant installed.(Check this)

run cmd :

ant -f core/build.xml

If error related to tools.jar comes, copy tools.jar to desired location.

Comment: yes ANT is installed(because when I type ANT in cmd for the directory that I have installed ANT (that is C:\program files),the build got error message that is Build:build.xml doesn't exist!  Build fail !

Comment: is it because they are not in same location? my work space is under another directory but ANT is in another directory. However, i put both ZXing and ANT under C:\program files...... is it not okay?

Comment: ant is not problem here , I think u r not giving correct path, and/or ur zxing project dnt have build.xml at core/build.xml

Comment: that is what i m wondering too, what is my ZXing project doesnt have build.xml ? because the proj is just a new project

Comment: just update that I got this compiled but still got this error  /build.xml:37: Compile failed;

Comment: my path for ZXing libarry/build.xml:37: Compile failed;

Comment: are u talking about project ZXING( android ) or main project source code on there site  ?

Comment: If u want to build core.jar , U need to build it from main source code, which has a 'core' folder and other folders like 'android'( which has android zxing project), 'iphone'(which has iphone zxing project) etc.

Comment: if u want core.jar tell me I ll give u mine, may be it is older version. :)

Comment: hey I just solved it, I was stupid just now for real ZXing2.0 library is still in the ZXing2.0 folder so it is like underneath one folder to another ! I just delete the extra layer and now it is fine ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Read the error: Access is denied

You have some kind of permissions problem in your local copy.