# Barcode Fragment (Zxing library)

Tags: android, android-fragments, barcode, zxing, barcode-scanner

I've been trying to get [this](https://code.google.com/p/barcodefragmentlib/wiki/HowTo) library to work in my android app, but I can't get it to work successfully. I have the fragment showing and the camera shows fine, but it doesn't seem to scan anything (QR, Barcodes etc). I've implemented the call back interface and still nothing happens.

If anyone could give a small example of how to set up the library to scan product codes (code 128) it would be a massive help!

Also, I've already looked at other related questions ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11558574/a-qr-scanner-inside-of-a-fragment) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782543/integration-zxing-library-directly-into-my-android-application)) and I still can't get it to work.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just released a library to help with that. It's inspired by the library you mentioned, but I needed compatibility with Android 2.1+. I hope it helps.

Link: https://github.com/welcu/zxingfragmentlib

Comment: Thanks for the library. I was able to compile it with Android Studio. I'm using maven in my project, is there a way to compile it to be used by maven?

Comment: I haven't found the time to do so (I have to learn how to do it yet). Hopefully I'll get into it in the coming weeks, any help will be appreciated!

Comment: when i tried to run this facing the following issue..
Error:(32, 13) Failed to resolve: com.google.zxing:core:3.1.0
<a href="openFile:D:/ASWorkspace/zxingfragmentlib-master/library/build.gradle">Show in File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>

Answer (score 2):

The library that you reffered has been depricated.
please use https://code.google.com/p/barcodefraglibv2/

Answer (score 0):

```
buttonScan = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_imei_scan);
buttonScan .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
                    intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "BAR_CODE_MODE");
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
            }
        });

@Override
    public void  onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        if (requestCode == 0) {
           if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK) {

              String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
              String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");

              Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"SCAN_RESULT --- >>>   " + contents , 
                      Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              // Handle successful scan

           } else if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_CANCELED) {
              // Handle cancel
              Log.i("App","Scan unsuccessful");
           }
      }
   }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But: Why should the OP try this code? A **good answer** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score 0):

**you can implement ZXingScanner into Fragment.**

**Official Documnent**

https://github.com/dm77/barcodescanner/blob/master/zxing-sample/src/main/java/me/dm7/barcodescanner/zxing/sample/FullScannerFragment.java

**Download source code using this link**

https://github.com/mitoyarzun/zxingfragmentlib