# Scan Barcode inside Fragment

Tags: android, fragment, barcode

I want to Scan a Barcode inside my Fragment. If I click on the Scan button the barcode Scanner pops up and scans the Barcode. But I cannot get the scanned text. Whats the problem with my onActivityResult method?

Background: Ive got two different scan buttons in my application. the first one scans qrcodes and is located in my `MainActivity`. It works fine and also my `onActivityResult`method works good. 
The second scan button is located in my AddDataFragment. With this button I want to scan Serials, based on regular barcodes. So I have 2 scan events and one `onActivityResult`....

EDIT: I changed my old false Code to my (hopefully) better Code.

This is the `onActivityResult`Code in my `MainActivity`. How do I get the scanned string (scannedResult) from my `MainActivity`to my `AddDataFragment`?

```js
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        if (requestCode == 0) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                String scanContent = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
                String scanFormat = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
                Log.d("INHALT", scanContent);
                Log.d("FORMAT", scanFormat);
                if (scanFormat == "QR_CODE"){
                    String [] Split = scanContent.split("\\s");
                    String product = Split[0];
                    String label = Split[1];
                    

                    mydb.insertData(product, label);
                } else {
                    scannedResult = scanContent;
                }



            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                // Handle cancel
            }
        }


        Fragment fragment;
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragment = new ListViewFragment();
        ft.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
        ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();
    }
```

This is the method I call in my `AddDataFragment`

```js
        inputSerial = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText_serial);
        ImageButton ib = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.button_scan_serial);
        ib.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
                intent.putExtra("SCAN_FORMATS", "CODE_39,CODE_93,CODE_128,DATA_MATRIX,ITF,CODABAR,EAN_13,EAN_8,UPC_A");
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

            }
        });
```

But it seems that the call of `onActivityResult`isnt working because I dont get the Log entrys after scanning a regular Barcode. (No crash or Error Message)

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11558574/a-qr-scanner-inside-of-a-fragment

Comment: It doesnt help. I think my code is correct because in my MainActivity it works. But maybe the code isnt correct arranged. Wrong position? Do the `onActivityResult` method has to be inside or outside the `onCreateView` and why?

Comment: onActivityResult in Fragment is the problem! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147884/onactivityresult-not-being-called-in-fragment

Comment: After hours of research I recognized this :D but now I have anotherProblem. How to get my scanned string back to my Fragment?

Comment: I changed my Question due to the expanded problem