# How to implement QR code scanner in Fragment in portrait mode in android?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, qr-code, zxing

I am developing an application,In this application I have to implement QR code scanner, I can achieve this thing easily  in activity with the help of Zxing library but the thing is that the scanner should be in fragment and the Fragment added in ViewPager and I also want customise the view of scanner.

Comment: You don't need a library other than Zxing... You described exactly what you need, so please add the code that you've written to implement that and describe the problem you are having implementing it

Answer (score -2):

For Android Studio Users

```
repositories {
 maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
    }
 }

compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.2.0@aar'
compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1'
```

First of all, you need to to trigger an intent by virtue of which camera gets open (Scanner).

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");                
intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
```

Then , If trigerred within a Fragment then write, else you will get your request code wrong.

```
getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

If From Activity

```
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

Then, it must be an Activity where you need your results captured by the scanner, I have captured and thus displayed in a Toast.

```
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        if (requestCode == 0) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
                String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
              Toast.makeText(this,contents,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                // Handle successful scan
            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                // Handle cancel
            }
        }
    }
```

Finally, Index it in manifest File, Use of intent filters enables it to recognise its source and function

```
<activity android:name="com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.CaptureActivity"
        android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
        android:stateNotNeeded="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: i want to use scanner in fragment and fragment has loaded in View Pager.