# Android ZXing QR code Scanner in selected User Interface,open camera in limited predefined space

Tags: android, fragment, qr-code, zxing

So far I am able to implement the scanner and i am fulfilling my scanner necessities that being in full screen mode by virtue of all available help material online.
But i have another functionality where i need it(camera) to open in predefined User Interface, as in a already defined fragment, but i am not able to achieve it, help me.

Comment: what you tried so far?

Comment: Your question is difficult to answer as it doesn't contain your code. You'll need to post your code so that people can look at it and point out where the problem is. It's preferred that you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also see [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You can use the "edit" button to update your question. Good luck!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35822289/3470479 Amy please have a look, to implement scanner I have used this code in my application but it is opening camera in full screen mode, I want it to open in a frame layout.