# Using zxing library program crash

Tags: android, zxing

I am having problems using zxing library. I do everything as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782543/integration-zxing-library-directly-into-my-android-application) answer. And then to use library I used [this](http://damianflannery.wordpress.com/2011/06/13/integrate-zxing-barcode-scanner-into-your-android-app-natively-using-eclipse/) tutorial. So I added core.jar in my app and a library zxing. I try to use it with this code

```java
Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

And when I compile and start my app and press button which calls this code, I get unexpected error and everything is just shut down. If I have a bar code scanner installed on my device and if I dont use this library, it works fine. But I have to use the app with phones without Internet connection, so I have to get this library working.

Thanks

Comment: Would be easier if you posted the error (crash) from the log

Comment: did you modify your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Ok that solved the problem, i modify manifest but make a mistake in it :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is `ActivityNotFoundException`. You are not checking to see if Barcode Scanner is installed. No, you do not need to modify your Manifest.

What you should do is use the provided instructions for integrating by Intent instead of trying to roll your own. Use `IntentIntegrator`: http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent