# Need help to use ZXing for encoding a text to QR code in android

Tags: android, zxing

I am trying to encode a text in to QR code by using ZXing. I have downloaded ZXing 2.0. Now I do not know how to do the rest of the things. Kindly tell me what I need to do next. All I want to do is to enter a text in to edittext and generate the QR code based on this text when I press button. I have seen many questions related to this topic but I was unable to find a suitable answer.

Kindly explain me the steps to follow. I also need to know what changes I have to make in the manifest for achieving this and how I can display it the QR code as bitmap in my activity

Answer (score 1):

Use the supplied `android-integration` library (not `core/`, not `android/`) to invoke Barcode Scanner by `Intent` to display the QR code for whatever text you like. It just a few lines of code: http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent

Answer (score 0):

To display an edittext as a QR code via Zxing, you can:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.ENCODE");
String data = edittext.getText().toString();
intent.putExtra("ENCODE_DATA", to_display);
intent.putExtra("ENCODE_TYPE", "TEXT_TYPE");
startActivity(intent);
```

To use this, you need to declare the ZXing EncodeActivity in your manifest, add the intent filter, etc.

In general, their code is very well documented. [Their project page](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/w/list) would be the best place to get started.

Comment: Can you kindly tell me what all files I need to copy from the downloaded ZXing 2.0 folder to my android project. Also explain the way for declaring the EncodeActivity inside the manifest.

Comment: You do *not* need to clone the code from Barcode Scanner to get this to work. In fact we discourage it, mostly because it's error prone.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `core.jar` from the latest ZXing source release to your project and add two more classes to your package.

This solution makes use of ZXing core library and *does not* require installing the third-party application (Barcode Scanner).

You just need to follow this [step-by-step guide](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15510698/1181911).