# Android Zxing library for qr code generation

Tags: android, zxing

I want to generate qr code of a text in my application i have to zxing library but I have no idea to implement this. how can I implement this?any help

Comment: Read documentation. Do it the intent way if possible. [Scanning Via Intent](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent)

Answer (score 3):

```
        QRCodeWriter writer = new QRCodeWriter();
        try
        {
            EnumMap<EncodeHintType, Object> hint = new EnumMap<EncodeHintType, Object>(EncodeHintType.class);
            hint.put(EncodeHintType.CHARACTER_SET, "UTF-8");
            BitMatrix bitMatrix = writer.encode(content, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, dimention, dimention, hint);
            int width = bitMatrix.getWidth();
            int height = bitMatrix.getHeight();
            int[] pixels = new int[width * height];
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
            {
                int offset = y * width;
                for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
                {
                    // pixels[offset + x] = bitMatrix.get(x, y) ? 0xFF000000
                    // : 0xFFFFFFFF;
                    pixels[offset + x] = bitMatrix.get(x, y) ? colorBack : colorFront;
                }
            }

            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            bitmap.setPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
            return bitmap;
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the `core.jar` file from the latest release of ZXing to your project.  You also need to add two more classes to your project.

Here is a [step-by-step guide](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15510698/1181911) on how to do so.

Answer (score 2):

```
below code can help you to generate qr code 

Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intents.Encode.ACTION);
intent.putExtra(Intents.Encode.FORMAT, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE.toString());
intent.putExtra(Intents.Encode.TYPE, Contents.Type.TEXT);
intent.putExtra(Intents.Encode.DATA, codeString);
QRCodeEncoder qrcode = new QRCodeEncoder(YourActivity.this, intent,250);

try {
Bitmap bitmap = qrcode.encodeAsBitmap();
imgBarcode = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgbarcode);
imgBarcode.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

} catch (WriterException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I got a problem with BarcodeFornat.QR_CODE.toString(), it says java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.zxing.BarcodeFormat , Can you help me? What version of Zxing library are you using?

Comment: Just write "QR_CODE" instead. You don't want to have to import classes like `BarcodeFormat` from core/.

Comment: @Marckaraujo  can i share Qrcode generated from this code ? if yes may i need to save this generated QRCode in device sdcard and then share

Comment: @ErumHannan, yes you can share this qrcode, you dont need to save the qrcode to share it, you just need to save if you want to share the qrcode not exactly after you take it.