# QR code generator in android

Tags: android, qr-code

I am planning to develop a QR code generator application for Android devices.

Can somebody please provide me some references to guide me on this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can visit [ZXING ("Zebra Crossing")](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/) and you can also find a working example [here](https://github.com/barmstrong/bitcoin-android/).

This is an example of 150x150 qr code of ZXING,

```
Bitmap bm = encodeAsBitmap(barcode_content, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, 150, 150);

if(bm != null) {
    image_view.setImageBitmap(bm);
}
```

Comment: What If I don't want to use any library to generate QRCode ? Is it possible to generate QRCode with custom code in Android?

Answer (score 4):

The [zxing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/) library is a good start.

There's also a [Google Charts API](https://developers.google.com/chart/infographics/docs/qr_codes#details) for generating QRCodes

Answer (score 3):

The best reference is certainly Zxing. An open source library available on code.google
See the following link : 
[Zxing library](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/)
You can find more information in the encoder class : 
[Encoder class link](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk#trunk/core/src/com/google/zxing/qrcode/encoder)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a network connection, maybe you could save time and use an online QR code interface like http://qrcode.loresoft.de/qr-code-interface

This is a free interface for private and commercial use without any limits (in German).

Answer (score 1):

Here is the perfect answer for generating QR codes without maven and etc
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15510698/3173384

You need only to put core.jar into libs in project

(can take int here http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/zxing/core/2.3.0/)

and put 2 classes Contents.java & QRCodeEncoder.java

Answer (score 1):

I gave up on using the Java libraries and opted for using a WebView with a JS library instead. Here's one JS lib: http://davidshimjs.github.io/qrcodejs/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is very late, but someone find it useful. I found one which is very tiny and smart library [QRGen](https://github.com/kenglxn/QRGen)

Sample Code:

```
Bitmap myBitmap = QRCode.from("www.example.org").bitmap();
ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
```

Answer (score 0):

https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=500x500&cht=qr&chl=data

Use this for generating qr code online. Then use picasso to load the image. ( Use your data in the url parameter )  I found it as the best way.