# Implementing Barcode Scanner

Tags: android, barcode-scanner

I am developing an app in which i have to use **Barcode Scanner** to scan Barcode and after lot of search i got the following code:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
```

With the help of this code , **user can implement barcode scanner of Zxing** but i want to implement my barcode scanner **programmatically** that is i **don't want a third party application**.
I used [Integrating the ZXing library directly into my Android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782543/integration-zxing-library-directly-into-my-android-application) link to make **standalone barcode** scanner but **i don't know what to do after making core.jar**
Kindly help me to integrate barcode scanner.
Any help will be appreciated..
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Launch activity for result instead or just the convenience code for this:

```
IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(yourActivity);
integrator.initiateScan();
```

and have this method to receive the result:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
  IntentResult scanResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
  if (scanResult != null) {
    // handle scan result
  }
  // else continue with any other code you need in the method
  ...
}
```

Please refer to this link for more information:

http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent

Comment: Can you please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782543/integration-zxing-library-directly-into-my-android-application and tell me what to do after core.jar for standalone barcode scanner

Comment: What I have seen from above method it ask to install one more application from play store and user775 had clearly mentioned `i don't want a third party application`.