# How to trigger Bulk scan mode using Zxing library in my app to scan multiple barcodes and qrcodes without showing a preview screen

Tags: android, zxing, barcode-scanner

Can anyone help me to achieve Bulk Scan Mode using Zxing library inside my app. What it does now is that after scanning a barcode the camera screen disappears and the scan result is populated on my Activity. But I need to do is scan multiple barcodes one after the other and then return back to my activity on back button press.

Answer (score 1):

You mean return several values back to the app? No it can't be set to do that. The app can export the scan history, and you can register as an app that can handle a share of `text/csv` data. Maybe that is roughly close enough to a solution.

Comment: Should I use the zxing project as a library as mentioned in here : http://damianflannery.wordpress.com/2011/06/13/integrate-zxing-barcode-scanner-into-your-android-app-natively-using-eclipse/ and can I have the privilage to make some modification in the source code so that I can achieve multiple barcode scan as per my requirements.

Comment: Related stuff with good answer can be found from here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4782543/1338846 It seems that only way to do any advanced stuff is to use it as library. Tonight I'll try to look for easy way to scan barcodes without preview but if I can't find ready made solution I must start developing one tomorrow. Most probably using Zxing library as base library. Simple reason behind doing this kind of stuff is requirements for industrial application.