# Error while converting text to QR code

Tags: android, barcode

I am trying to create a text to QR code converter.

I used the core2.2.jar from http://code.google.com/p/zxing/downloads/list and the code as told in [Integrating the ZXing library directly into my Android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782543/integration-zxing-library-directly-into-my-android-application/6230861#6230861).

My Main.Activity is as shown below

package com.example.qr_androidone;

```
import com.google.zxing.BarcodeFormat;
import com.google.zxing.WriterException;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.qrCode);

        String qrData = "Data I want to encode in QR code";
        int qrCodeDimention = 500;

        QRCodeEncoder qrCodeEncoder = new QRCodeEncoder(qrData, null,
                Contents.Type.TEXT, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE.toString(), qrCodeDimention);

        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = qrCodeEncoder.encodeAsBitmap();
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (WriterException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

I used the "Contents.java" and "QRCodeEncoder.java" as shown in link [Integrating the ZXing library directly into my Android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782543/integration-zxing-library-directly-into-my-android-application/6230861#6230861). I changed "activity_main.xml" also , as shown in above link

There are no errors in compiling, but there is error when the app runs

> Could not find class 'com.google.zxing.EncodeHintType', referenced
>   from method com.example.qr_androidone.QRCodeEncoder.encodeAsBitmap
>
> Could not find class 'com.google.zxing.MultiFormatWriter', referenced
>   from method com.example.qr_androidone.QRCodeEncoder.encodeAsBitmap
>
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.zxing.BarcodeFormat

Please help me solve the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download de JAR file, go to your Build Path and Import it from External JARs.

http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/zxing/core/2.2/

Then import it in your project.

Answer (score 0):

you need the class of QRCodeEncoder.java..

```
public class QRCodeEncoder {
 private static final int WHITE = 0xFFFFFFFF;
    private static final int BLACK = 0xFF000000;

//      private int dimension = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    private String contents = null;
    private String displayContents = null;
    private String title = null;
    private BarcodeFormat format = null;
    private boolean encoded = false;

    public QRCodeEncoder(String data, Bundle bundle, String type, String format) {
   //           this.dimension = dimension;
        encoded = encodeContents(data, bundle, type, format);
    }

    public String getContents() {
        return contents;
    }

    public String getDisplayContents() {
        return displayContents;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    private boolean encodeContents(String data, Bundle bundle, String type, String formatString) {
        // Default to QR_CODE if no format given.
        format = null;
        if (formatString != null) {
            try {
                format = BarcodeFormat.valueOf(formatString);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
                // Ignore it then
            }
        }
        if (format == null || format == BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE) {
            this.format = BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE;
            encodeQRCodeContents(data, bundle, type);
        } else if (data != null && data.length() > 0) {
            contents = data;
            displayContents = data;
            title = "Text";
        }
        return contents != null && contents.length() > 0;
    }

    private void encodeQRCodeContents(String data, Bundle bundle, String type) {
        if (type.equals(Contents.Type.TEXT)) {
            if (data != null && data.length() > 0) {
                contents = data;
                displayContents = data;
                title = "Text";
            }
        } else if (type.equals(Contents.Type.EMAIL)) {
            data = trim(data);
            if (data != null) {
                contents = "mailto:" + data;
                displayContents = data;
                title = "E-Mail";
            }
        } else if (type.equals(Contents.Type.PHONE)) {
            data = trim(data);
            if (data != null) {
                contents = "tel:" + data;
                displayContents = PhoneNumberUtils.formatNumber(data);
                title = "Phone";
            }
        } else if (type.equals(Contents.Type.SMS)) {
            data = trim(data);
            if (data != null) {
                contents = "sms:" + data;
                displayContents = PhoneNumberUtils.formatNumber(data);
                title = "SMS";
            }
        } else if (type.equals(Contents.Type.CONTACT)) {
            if (bundle != null) {
                StringBuilder newContents = new StringBuilder(100);
                StringBuilder newDisplayContents = new StringBuilder(100);

                newContents.append("MECARD:");

                String name = trim(bundle.getString(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.NAME));
                if (name != null) {
                    newContents.append("N:").append(escapeMECARD(name)).append(';');
                    newDisplayContents.append(name);
                }

                String address = trim(bundle.getString(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.POSTAL));
                if (address != null) {
                    newContents.append("ADR:").append(escapeMECARD(address)).append(';');
                    newDisplayContents.append('\n').append(address);
                }

                Collection<String> uniquePhones = new HashSet<String>(Contents.PHONE_KEYS.length);
                for (int x = 0; x < Contents.PHONE_KEYS.length; x++) {
                    String phone = trim(bundle.getString(Contents.PHONE_KEYS[x]));
                    if (phone != null) {
                        uniquePhones.add(phone);
                    }
                }
                for (String phone : uniquePhones) {
                    newContents.append("TEL:").append(escapeMECARD(phone)).append(';');
                    newDisplayContents.append('\n').append(PhoneNumberUtils.formatNumber(phone));
                }

                Collection<String> uniqueEmails = new HashSet<String>(Contents.EMAIL_KEYS.length);
                for (int x = 0; x < Contents.EMAIL_KEYS.length; x++) {
                    String email = trim(bundle.getString(Contents.EMAIL_KEYS[x]));
                    if (email != null) {
                        uniqueEmails.add(email);
                    }
                }
                for (String email : uniqueEmails) {
                    newContents.append("EMAIL:").append(escapeMECARD(email)).append(';');
                    newDisplayContents.append('\n').append(email);
                }

                String url = trim(bundle.getString(Contents.URL_KEY));
                if (url != null) {
                    // escapeMECARD(url) -> wrong escape e.g. http\://zxing.google.com
                    newContents.append("URL:").append(url).append(';');
                    newDisplayContents.append('\n').append(url);
                }

                String note = trim(bundle.getString(Contents.NOTE_KEY));
                if (note != null) {
                    newContents.append("NOTE:").append(escapeMECARD(note)).append(';');
                    newDisplayContents.append('\n').append(note);
                }

                // Make sure we've encoded at least one field.
                if (newDisplayContents.length() > 0) {
                    newContents.append(';');
                    contents = newContents.toString();
                    displayContents = newDisplayContents.toString();
                    title = "Contact";
                } else {
                    contents = null;
                    displayContents = null;
                }
            }
        } else if (type.equals(Contents.Type.LOCATION)) {
            if (bundle != null) {
                float latitude = bundle.getFloat("LAT", Float.MAX_VALUE);
                float longitude = bundle.getFloat("LONG", Float.MAX_VALUE);
                if (latitude != Float.MAX_VALUE && longitude != Float.MAX_VALUE) {
                    contents = "geo:" + latitude + ',' + longitude;
                    displayContents = latitude + "," + longitude;
                    title = "Location";
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public Bitmap encodeAsBitmap() throws WriterException {
        if (!encoded) return null;

        Hashtable<EncodeHintType, String> hints = null;
        String encoding = guessAppropriateEncoding(contents);
        if (encoding != null) {
        hints = new Hashtable<EncodeHintType, String>();
        hints.put(EncodeHintType.CHARACTER_SET, encoding);
        }
        MultiFormatWriter writer = new MultiFormatWriter();
        BitMatrix result =writer.encode(contents, format, 300, 300, hints);
        int width = result.getWidth();
        int height =result.getHeight();
        int[] pixels = new int[width * height];
        // All are 0, or black, by default
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        int offset = y * width;
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {

        if(result.get(x, y) )
        {
        pixels[offset + x] = BLACK ;
        }
        else
        pixels[offset + x] = WHITE ;

        }
        }

        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        bitmap.setPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
        return bitmap;
        }

    private static String guessAppropriateEncoding(CharSequence contents) {
        // Very crude at the moment
        for (int i = 0; i < contents.length(); i++) {
            if (contents.charAt(i) > 0xFF) { return "UTF-8"; }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private static String trim(String s) {
        if (s == null) { return null; }
        String result = s.trim();
        return result.length() == 0 ? null : result;
    }

    private static String escapeMECARD(String input) {
        if (input == null || (input.indexOf(':') < 0 && input.indexOf(';') < 0)) { return input; }
        int length = input.length();
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(length);
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            char c = input.charAt(i);
            if (c == ':' || c == ';') {
                result.append('\\');
            }
            result.append(c);
        }
        return result.toString();
    }
```

}

and also need content.java class..

```
public class Contents {
private Contents() {
}

public static final class Type {

    public static final String TEXT = "TEXT_TYPE";
    public static final String EMAIL = "EMAIL_TYPE";
    public static final String PHONE = "PHONE_TYPE";
    public static final String SMS = "SMS_TYPE";
    public static final String CONTACT = "CONTACT_TYPE";
    public static final String LOCATION = "LOCATION_TYPE";

    private Type() {
    }
}

public static final String URL_KEY = "URL_KEY";

public static final String NOTE_KEY = "NOTE_KEY";

public static final String[] PHONE_KEYS = {
        ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.PHONE, ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.SECONDARY_PHONE,
        ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.TERTIARY_PHONE
};

public static final String[] PHONE_TYPE_KEYS = {
        ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.PHONE_TYPE,
        ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.SECONDARY_PHONE_TYPE,
        ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.TERTIARY_PHONE_TYPE
};

public static final String[] EMAIL_KEYS = {
        ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.EMAIL, ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.SECONDARY_EMAIL,
        ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.TERTIARY_EMAIL
};

public static final String[] EMAIL_TYPE_KEYS = {
        ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.EMAIL_TYPE,
        ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.SECONDARY_EMAIL_TYPE,
        ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.TERTIARY_EMAIL_TYPE
};
}
```

also need the core.jar file..
its perfectly work...