# ZXing integration issue

Tags: android, zxing

I want to integrate ZXing in my project as a lib and I don't want my users have to download the barcode scanner app from the Google Play...

I've read a lot of things on Google but I'm not able to integrate ZXing 2.3.0 in my android project.

Could someone help me?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782543/integration-zxing-library-directly-into-my-android-application?rq=1

Comment: Ok thanks, but this example show how to generated a qr code but I want  my app read codes... ;)

Comment: Please read the 'answer' to that question above. If there is something there that doesn't make sense or run into another question ask a follow up question. That answer should cover your question.

Comment: The Q/A I linked shows everything you need to embed ZXing in your project, which should be more than enough to start with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this library - https://github.com/embarkmobile/zxing-android-minimal. It offers a minimal ZXing setup to include directly into your app without need to download the barcode scanner app from the Google Play. It's easy to use and it's available as dependency for Gradle and Maven (no need to build original ZXing library from sources as suggested in another topic).