# Camera application with barcode reader in android

Tags: android, eclipse, barcode, zxing, barcode-scanner

I have implemented a simple camera application now i have to make it work for barcode reader. i already read some tutorials that suggest the zxing library for this. can some one help me out how to integrate zxing library in eclipse.

Comment: Check my detailed answer on [how to use ZXing in Android app](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30572168/165071)