# Using ZXing to generate QRCode on Android device without GooglePlayServices?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, qr-code, zxing

I only need to **generate** a `QRCode`, I **do not** need to scan the `QRCode`.

I can successfully generate the `QRCode`, but when I generate said code on an Android device without `Google Play Services` installed, I receive an error alert for a split second. But the error alert leaves the screen almost immediately and the `QRCode` is successfully displayed. The error alert is on the screen for such a short amount of time that you can't even read it.

The error alert says this:

> This app won't run without Google Play services, Which are missing from your phone.

Despite this 'error' alert, the app runs fine and the `QRCode` is still successfully generated.

Can anyone tell me if this is a bug in the `ZXing` library? Or if there's something wrong with my implementation? I don't want the 'error' alert displayed, and the alert appears to be wrong because the app runs fine and the `QRCode` is still generated perfectly.

I've included a screen shot of the 'error' alert (it was hard to snap a screen shot because it as on the screen for such a short amount of time).

[image: QRCode generation 'error']

**QR Generation Code:**

```
private Bitmap encodeAsBitmap(String str) throws WriterException {

    try {
        result = new MultiFormatWriter().encode(str, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, width, height, null);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
        // Unsupported format
        return null;
    }

    int width = result.getWidth();
    int height = result.getHeight();
    int[] pixels = new int[width * height];
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        int offset = y * width;
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            pixels[offset + x] = result.get(x, y) ? BLACK : WHITE;
        }
    }

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    bitmap.setPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
    return bitmap;
}
```

**Update**: I followed this SO post to help with the generation: [QRCode Generation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28232116/2371425).

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski, that's not a very constructive comment.  Please excuse me for trying to ask if anyone else has experienced this issue, I'd like to know if this is a bug or if I've done something wrong before I do go with something else...

Comment: You can try to use these [codes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14207326/4186942) to generate a barcode via zxing. Also, it might be a internal bug and you can report here:https://github.com/zxing/zxing/issues

Comment: @bjiang, I'm using pretty much that same method. So I'm kind of thinking that it might actually be an internal bug. I'll look into things a little bit more before submitting a bug report. Thank you :)

Comment: No problem, glad to help:)

Comment: Apparently the error alert does not affect the ZXing library. So it's safe to use.

Answer (score 0):

The error alert is part of the Android barcode service, it doesn't affect the ZXing app/library, so there's nothing to worry about.