# Generating QR Code for android Audio Manager

Tags: android, qr-code, zxing, android-audiomanager

I want to build an android application to generate QR Code based on audio settings(silent mode etc.) and later scan that QR & change the phone settings accordingly automatically just by scanning the QR. Would you please tell me how can i do it? I will use ZXing library. But how to integrate those settings to generate QR and later pass those settings to scanner to change phone settings finally? Thanks for the help. Let me know if you have any further questions. A sample code/reference is always appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create QR codes off strings, so you can generate qr codes off strings such as "silent-mode" etc. And when the code is scanned, you can take the scanned string to accordingly make changes to the audio settings.

**Here is how to create a QR Code off a string in ZXing Library:**

[Android Using ZXing Generate QR Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28232116/android-using-zxing-generate-qr-code)

**Here is a tutorial on how to change audio settings:**

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_audiomanager.htm

You can combine those two to create the app you want.