# QR-encode a String to Image in Android project using zxing

Tags: android, zxing, eclipse-adt

I am trying to create [a simple Android app](https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/tree/master/QREncoder), which would display a QR-coded image - by using [zxing library](https://github.com/zxing/zxing).

So I have installed `HomeBrew`, `ant` and `maven` at my Mac OS Yosemite notebook and pointed the `ANDROID_HOME` environment variable to the location of Android SDK.

Then I have checked out latest zxing from GitHub and built it (seeming without any errors) with the command `mvn package` (and using `javac` version 1.8.0_45).

After that I have created a new Android project with blank Activity in Eclipse and copied the 3 jar files into its `libs` directory:

- android/libs/core-3.2.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
- android-core/target/android-core-3.2.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
- android/target/android-4.7.4.jar

Unfortunately, my simple code in [MainActivity.java](https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/blob/master/QREncoder/src/de/afarber/qrencoder/MainActivity.java) does not compile:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.qrCode);
    String qrData = "Data I want to encode in QR code";
    int qrCodeDimention = 500;
    QRCodeEncoder qrCodeEncoder = new QRCodeEncoder(qrData, 
            null,
            Contents.Type.TEXT, 
            BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE.toString(), 
            qrCodeDimention);

    try {
        Bitmap bitmap = qrCodeEncoder.encodeAsBitmap();
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    } catch (WriterException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The errors are (here [fullscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycE15.png)):

[image: eclipse screenshot]

```
BarcodeFormat cannot be resolved
Contents cannot be resolved to a variable
QRCodeEncoder cannot be resolved to a type
QRCodeEncoder cannot be resolved to a type
WriterException cannot be resolved to a type
```

But at the same time I can see these (supposedly not found by Eclipse) classes by calling `tar` tool:

```
# tar tvfz libs/core-3.2.1-SNAPSHOT.jar | grep -i WriterException
-rwxrwxrwx  0 0 0 0 28 Mai 20:35 com/google/zxing/WriterException.class
# tar tvfz libs/core-3.2.1-SNAPSHOT.jar | grep -i BarcodeFormat
-rwxrwxrwx  0 0 0 0 28 Mai 20:35 com/google/zxing/BarcodeFormat.class
# tar tvfz libs/android-4.7.4.jar | grep -i QRCodeEncoder
-rwxrwxrwx  0 0 0 0 28 Mai 20:39 com/google/zxing/client/android/encode/QRCodeEncoder.class
```

What am I doint wrong please, why can't Eclipse find the classes?

I have asked my question [at GitHub](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/issues/398) as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, I've fixed my problem (of generating a QR-encoded image from a string) by looking at the [android/src/com/google/zxing/client/android/encode/QRCodeEncoder.java](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/blob/master/android/src/com/google/zxing/client/android/encode/QRCodeEncoder.java):

[image: screenshot]

Here is my [MainActivity.java](https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/blob/master/QREncoder/src/de/afarber/qrencoder/MainActivity.java):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.qrCode);
    try {
        Bitmap bitmap = encodeAsBitmap(STR);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    } catch (WriterException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

Bitmap encodeAsBitmap(String str) throws WriterException {
    BitMatrix result;
    try {
        result = new MultiFormatWriter().encode(str, 
            BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, WIDTH, WIDTH, null);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
        // Unsupported format
        return null;
    }
    int w = result.getWidth();
    int h = result.getHeight();
    int[] pixels = new int[w * h];
    for (int y = 0; y < h; y++) {
        int offset = y * w;
        for (int x = 0; x < w; x++) {
            pixels[offset + x] = result.get(x, y) ? BLACK : WHITE;
        }
    }
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    bitmap.setPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, w, h);
    return bitmap;
}
```

Also, I have taken **core.jar** from [Maven repository](http://search.maven.org) (here [fullscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXYMV.png)):

[image: eclipse screenshot]

Finally, riginal problem of Eclipse not being able to use jar files I've built with Maven was coming from the Java version - to be fixed in *Project Properties* or *Eclipse Settings*:

[image: JDK screenshot]