# not able to import Zxing Library in android project

Tags: android, zxing

I am using zxing released build 3.2. Download it from git hub and import it in eclipse. After importing I set java compiler as 1.7 and add core.jar but still there is some error in library please give me suggestion to resolve it.

thanks in advance.

Comment: R cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: this accepted answers may help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7824730/r-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-variable

Comment: I have provide a simple solution on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782543/integration-zxing-library-directly-into-my-android-application/34941618#34941618

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it easier to use zxing via Intent ? (https://github.com/zxing/zxing/wiki/Scanning-Via-Intent)

```
IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(yourActivity);
integrator.initiateScan();

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
  IntentResult scanResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
  if (scanResult != null) {
    // handle scan result
  }
  // else continue with any other code you need in the method
  ...
}
```