# how to add barcode scan in android app without using another app and support letest android version?

Tags: android, barcode, zxing

I need a barcode scanner in my android app withiout using third party app. I am using android studio. I have try bellow link for barcode scanner. Barcode scanner is open but not reading barcode.
[Integrating the ZXing library directly into my Android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782543/integrating-the-zxing-library-directly-into-my-android-application)

Comment: can you add some code how you did it?

Comment: There is also an option using google play services [Mobile Vision Barcode API](https://developers.google.com/vision/android/barcodes-overview)

Answer (score 7):

You can easily implement a bar code scanner on your own by using Google's Mobile Vision api which provides an api for bar code detection. They have provided a very simple yet excellent tutorial to implement it. Here's the link to it : https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/barcodes

Answer (score 5):

Hello I solved this using GitHub sample project.
Link is https://github.com/dm77/barcodescanner