# Scan QR code - public key

Tags: android, qr-code

I am using QR code scanning, and search something that I don't find anywhere.
I would like to scan a QR code, which scan a private key and it return me a public key.

How is it feasible?

Comment: Try [Zxing](https://github.com/zxing/zxing)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Integrating the ZXing library directly into my Android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782543/integrating-the-zxing-library-directly-into-my-android-application)

Answer (score 1):

Add the following dependency to your `build.gradle` file.:

```
compile 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9.8'
```

Add camera permission to your `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

reference : https://github.com/dm77/barcodescanner

Comment: I implemented it properly and it don't works. When the scan start it does a Out focus and Re focus. i'am on a Galaxy S6.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there are no public\private keys in QR code. The QR code is only **a representation of a data**. As such, it can represent an http link (when the data is a string), or a public key for bitcoin transaction (when the data is binary \ string), and other things...
Once you get your qr code scanned, you can treat it as a public key and do magic to find related private key, this is not the scope of this answer.

For your question, in order to scan a QR code you can use google-play services.
Basically you need to initiate a BarcodeDetector, init a Frame with your bitmap from your camera, and search for barcodes.

code snippet:

```
BarcodeDetector detector = 
    new BarcodeDetector.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                        .setBarcodeFormats(Barcode.DATA_MATRIX | Barcode.QR_CODE)
                        .build();

if(!detector.isOperational()){
   // we have a problem
   return;
}

Frame frame = new Frame.Builder().setBitmap(yourBitmapHere).build();
SparseArray<Barcode> barcodes = detector.detect(frame);

Barcode qrCode = barcodes.valueAt(0);
String qrCodeValue = qrCode.rawValue;
```

Go to their full [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/bar-codes/#0) to see more details (including gradle, imports, etc).

Comment: Thanks you, does it request a internet connection when using it?