# Android : Searching items using there barcodes in ebay

Tags: java, android

I have a project idea for my college project to develop an android application which can take images of the bar codes of various electronic equipments like cameras laptops and then to read models and brands of them using that bar codes and then to search for that model and brand in Ebay to point the user to relevant web pages. I want to know that is it possible to do this project ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible- Start with this example of [How to Scan Barcodes on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4955110/1167780) and then check out the [Ebay Java SDK](https://www.x.com/developers/ebay/documentation-tools/sdks/java) (Specifically see this tutorial titled: [Getting Started with the Finding API: Finding Items by Keywords](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/finding/HowTo/GettingStarted_JS_NV_JSON/GettingStarted_JS_NV_JSON.html))

Comment: Thanks for your answer I'll check :)