# Zxing Reader Install in user

Tags: android, zxing

I want to implement a barcode reader in my android app. If I employ Zxing in my application, is it necessary for my user to download Zxing also? Or I can integrate the code in the app so that the users do not need to download it seperately?

Comment: I think you are confusing ZXing and Barcode Scanner. The former is a jar you can include in your project. The latter is an application using ZXing library. Most of times you'll be fine invoking BarcodeScanner via Intent and getting back the result.

Comment: That means the user do not need to download another application if I include jar in my project??

Comment: That means you'll have to show the camera, take a snapshot, pass it to ZXing library for decoding, and manage errors by yourself. If you want live scanning, you'll have to implement it on your own as well. ZXing only decodes, everything else is up to you. With BarcodeScanner gou get all that out of the box.

Comment: Thanks so much!! Can I also know how can i incuded jar in my project and what to download?

Comment: You can download the full multi-platform library here: http://code.google.com/p/zxing/downloads/detail?name=ZXing-2.0.zip&can=2&q= . Most likely you'll only need the core (core folder, look for core.jar). In the Android folder you have a sample client.

Comment: I had download it sucessfully.
Can u give me a step-by-step action to use the library and have a test? I am new to android app development. Thanks

Comment: Refer to the source code of the sample android client included in the zip.

Comment: Sorry, how can see the source code in the sample client and which folder u refer to?

Answer (score 2):

I think that you are talking about the Barcode Scanner application based on Zxing library. Your application will call Barcode Scanner via Intent and getting back the result. So, you  must catch ActivityNotFoundException. You can use IntentIntegrator, which does all of this for you: [IntentIntegrator](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent)

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can integrate by Intent, which does not require embedding the library. The provided integration code will handle installing the app if it is not present. http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent

Answer (score 0):

I think user must install Zxing barcode reader application in their device to work with Bar code reader.

Also refer [This Answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4854637/1405983)

Comment: The app is Barcode Scanner. It needs to be installed to invoke it by Intent, but this can be handled automatically. It does *not* require using the library.