# Zxing lib supports Barcode scanning in Android

Tags: android, barcode, zxing

With Zxing lib, I'm able to scan QR code efficiently, bot I'm not able to scan Barcode scanning. I did lots of RnD and different different piece of code tested, but not workig.

So, My question -

1. is Zxing libs supports Barcode scanning in Android ?
2. If supports, should I use different zxing lib or same lib (QR_Code) lib will work ?

Any pointer/suggestion please.

Zxing lib Supported code -

List of barcode formats supported by ZXING

```
1.  QR_CODE
2.  DATA_MATRIX
3.  UPC_E
4.  UPC_A
5.  EAN_8
6.  EAN_13
7.  UPC_EAN_EXTENSION
8.  CODE_128
9.  CODE_39
```

10.  CODE_93
   11.  CODABAR
   12.  ITF
   13.  RSS14
   14.  PDF417
   15.  RSS_EXPANDED

Used code snapshot -

Option 1 -

```
Intent objIntent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN"); 
            objIntent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE"); 
            objIntent.putExtra("SCAN_FORMATS", "CODABAR"); 
            startActivityForResult(objIntent, 0);
```

Option 2 -

```
  Intent objIntent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN"); 
            objIntent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "PRODUCT_MODE""); 
            objIntent.putExtra("SCAN_FORMATS", "UPC_A"); 
            startActivityForResult(objIntent, 0);
```

Option 3 -

```
  Intent objIntent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN"); 
            objIntent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "PRODUCT_MODE""); 
            objIntent.putExtra("SCAN_FORMATS", "UPC_A"); 
            startActivityForResult(objIntent, 0);
```

Option 4 -

```
      Intent objIntent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN"); 
            objIntent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE"); 
            startActivityForResult(objIntent, 0);
```

I'm interested to scan only barcode not QR code -

[image: Barcode sample image]

Comment: List of barcode formats supported by ZXING



1. QR_CODE
2. DATA_MATRIX
3. UPC_E
4. UPC_A
5. EAN_8
6. EAN_13
7. UPC_EAN_EXTENSION
8. CODE_128
9. CODE_39
10. CODE_93
11. CODABAR
12. ITF
13. RSS14
14. PDF417
15. RSS_EXPANDED

Comment: u resolved your issue ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, ZXing lib supports regular barcodes.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you go for Zbar library, that seems more easy to implement. 
Yes But if you want like Zxing's customized camera scanner you'll have to customize the surface of scanner camera otherwise, it'll fulfil you're requirement.

[**Here is the link for library with a sample too.**](https://github.com/DushyanthMaguluru/ZBarScanner)

If you'll look to the sample , you can see there are two functions , one is for scanning both qr as well bar code. and other is for only qr code.

```
// This will scan both
 public void launchScanner(View v) {
        if (isCameraAvailable()) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, ZBarScannerActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, ZBAR_SCANNER_REQUEST);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Rear Facing Camera Unavailable", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }


//this will scan only qr code
    public void launchQRScanner(View v) {
        if (isCameraAvailable()) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, ZBarScannerActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(ZBarConstants.SCAN_MODES, new int[]{Symbol.QRCODE});
            startActivityForResult(intent, ZBAR_SCANNER_REQUEST);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Rear Facing Camera Unavailable", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Use As per your need.

**Following barcodes are supported by Zbar  :**

PARTIAL, EAN8, UPCEISBN10, UPCA, EAN13, ISBN13, I25, DATABAR, DATABAR_EXP, CODABAR, CODE39  PDF417, QRCODE, CODE93, CODE128 .

Answer (score 0):

ZXing supports many barcode formats: UPC_A, UPC_E, EAN_8, EAN_13, CODE_39, CODE_93, CODE_128, and more.

The simplest way to use ZXing is with the android-integration they provide, it's also [the way they want people to use it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4854637/912408). I have an [example project on github](https://github.com/SingingBush/android-barcodescanner-zxing) which shows how to use ZXing this way. Essentially you'll need to do something like this:

```
private void scanBarcode() {
    IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(getActivity());
    Collection<String> BARCODE_TYPES =
            Collections.unmodifiableCollection(Arrays.asList("UPC_A", "EAN_8", "EAN_13"));
    integrator.initiateScan(BARCODE_TYPES);
}
```

If you want to use it directly then it would be best to checkout [their code from github](https://github.com/zxing/zxing). From what I recall it is the *CaptureActivity* that you want to start.

It is also worth checkout out [ZBar](https://github.com/ZBar/ZBar).