# error when try using zxing library

Tags: android, zxing, barcode-scanner

i want to have barcode scanner on my android application.I try to follow intruction from this [Using ZXing to create an android barcode scanning app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050263/using-zxing-to-create-an-android-barcode-scanning-app/2051953#2051953) and looking good because i've barcodeScanner app being installed on my phone that i wasnt realize before. when i try to another phone when i want to scan barcode it ask me to download barcodeScanner. my issue is like this thread [Embed Zxing library without using Barcode Scanner app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4854442/embed-zxing-library-without-using-barcode-scanner-app) and follow instruction.but i got an error in this line `super.onResume();`.here is my error logcat

```
04-17 16:00:51.735: E/AndroidRuntime(6138): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-17 16:00:51.735: E/AndroidRuntime(6138): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {ims.app.salesmarket/ims.app.salesmarket.EntryTO}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-17 16:00:51.735: E/AndroidRuntime(6138):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2595)
04-17 16:00:51.735: E/AndroidRuntime(6138):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2623)
04-17 16:00:51.735: E/AndroidRuntime(6138):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2109)
04-17 16:00:51.735: E/AndroidRuntime(6138):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:134)
04-17 16:00:51.735: E/AndroidRuntime(6138):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247)
04-17 16:00:51.735: E/AndroidRuntime(6138):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-17 16:00:51.735: E/AndroidRuntime(6138):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
04-17 16:00:51.735: E/AndroidRuntime(6138):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4624)
04-17 16:00:51.735: E/AndroidRuntime(6138):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-17 16:00:51.735: E/AndroidRuntime(6138):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-17 16:00:51.735: E/AndroidRuntime(6138):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809)
04-17 16:00:51.735: E/AndroidRuntime(6138):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576)
04-17 16:00:51.735: E/AndroidRuntime(6138):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-17 16:00:51.735: E/AndroidRuntime(6138): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-17 16:00:51.735: E/AndroidRuntime(6138):     at com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity.onResume(CaptureActivity.java:163)
04-17 16:00:51.735: E/AndroidRuntime(6138):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1159)
04-17 16:00:51.735: E/AndroidRuntime(6138):     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:4553)
04-17 16:00:51.735: E/AndroidRuntime(6138):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2581)
04-17 16:00:51.735: E/AndroidRuntime(6138):     ... 12 more
```

how do i fix them?
every help will be apriciated.thank you for your kindness.

Comment: Well, what happened on line 163 of your modified copy of `CaptureActivity`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had faced the same problem. I tried to fix it by a couple of ways, and both of them eventually worked!!

1. Go to onResume() at CaptureActivity.java. Comment the whole function except the line super.onResume(). Next, add the following lines into your activity:

> `@Override`
>   public void onResume(){
>    super.onResume();
>   }

1. You could use the example from this link - http://khurramitdeveloper.blogspot.in/p/android-barcode-scan-using-zxing-library.html. It works for me without any hitch!